# Сумма чисел в строке

Tags: java

Доброго всем времени суток. Попрошу глянуть на код и сказать, где я натупил))

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Zad3 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c = ' ';
        char d = ' ';
        int symma=0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Vvedite 4isla");
        String str = scan.next();
        for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
            c = str.charAt(i);  
            d = str.charAt(i+1);
            symma = (int)c+(int)d;
        }
        System.out.println(symma);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это зависит от того, чего вы хотите добиться.

Покамест ваша программа считает сумму кодов последних двух цифр введённого числа, но, возможно, вам именно это и нужно?

Comment: не совсем)) нужно посчитать сумму всех введенных цифр.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал применить `Integer.parseInt(str)` для получения числа из строки. Разумеется, правильнее будет это выражение окружить блоком try{}, либо заранее проверять, не введено ли недопустимое значение.

Comment: ну, тогда всё неправильно)

1. вы на каждой итерации "забываете" о предыдущих слагаемых
2. вы неправильно приводите символ к его числовому значению
3. соответственно когда вы это поправите, у вас будет неправильное условие выхода из цикла

Comment: Складываете коды цифр вместо цифр.

Answer (score 3):

Не вдаваясь в холивары касательно качества кода и сравнения c C# (sic!), отмечу, что ключевое место где у вас ошибка это строки:

```
c = str.charAt(i);   
d = str.charAt(i+1); 
symma = (int)c+(int)d;
```

При таком подходе ваш код суммирует бинарные значения `c` и `d`, а хотелось, видимо числовых значений.

Необходимо:

1. Разбить строку их входного потока на 2 строки неким разделителем, например пробел - тогда `String[] s=str.split(" ");`
2. Полученные строки распарсить как число типа: `Double.parseDouble(s[i]);`

Comment: Что и было показано в ответе выше.

Comment: Конечно, я просто решил "разжевать" без нравоучений и холиваров.

Answer (score 2):

Код не претендует на звание идеального, но я специально упростил его.
Попробуйте сами понять зачем и как работает каждая строка, функция и символ.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Vvedite 4isla 4erez probel");
    String str = scan.next();
    String[] numbers = str.split(" ");
    int res = 0;
    try{
        for (String s : numbers) {
            res += Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
        System.out.println("Summa: " + res);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Vveli ne chisla!");
    }
```

Comment: Я бы так же реализовал, в качестве примера.

Comment: Для сравнения, на C#:

    Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine().Split().Sum(int.Parse));

Comment: @VladD, этим Вы кинули какашку в сторону джавы, намекая "вот он какой хороший этот сишарп!"?

Comment: @Евгений Карпов нет же, это просто "+" в сторону композитного программирования, такой себе протест против паттернов типа "for:for:if" :D

Comment: 2 @VladD : меня все время интересовало каким образом примеры С# помогут в изучении языка java? Внимание, правильный ответ: никаким. Единственной целью таких камментов является "холивар" (это показывает неуважение в первую очередь к себе)

осмелюсь предположить, что опытному С задроту язык, до мозга костей пронизаный духом ООП, оказался слишком сложным для восприятия (ведь столько шаблонов в мозгу сопротивляются ему). Произошло отторжение и сьезд на С# (туда вам дорога, да, мы рады этому)

p.s.s. дабы быть последовательным и не предвзятым добавляйте примеры и на других языках  (С, Asm, итд итп

Comment: @jmu: не совсем. Во-первых, в линейке языков, основанных на Java, есть языки с функциональным синтаксисом, например, Scala. Во-вторых, Java развивается в функциональную сторону, и не в последнюю очередь благодаря сравнению её с C# — вспомните, например, планируемые лямбда-функции и замыкания. Мне кажется, мой пример демонстрирует скорее преимущества функционального подхода, чем конкретного языка (на Python'е было бы не длиннее, но я его не настолько хорошо знаю).

Comment: @jmu: Я и вправду несколько предвзят по отношению к языкам, которые останавливаются в своём развитии. Я не настолько хорошо знаю ассемблеры, чтобы смастерить на каком-то из них поучительный пример; а работа со строками на чистом C (который я бесконечно уважаю) тоже не относится к числу его "приятных" особенностей. По поводу ООП, я не считаю его догмой, и не вижу необходимость жертвовать лёгкостью восприятия кода в пользу абстрактной идеи "всё есть объект". Осмелюсь напомнить, основное преимущество ООП есть и остаётся _большая_ понятность и читаемость кода по сравнению со спагетти-подходом.

Comment: 2 @Vlad: возможно вы не в курсе но большинство кода который пишут новички использует только базовые классы (т.е. основу языка) которая была создана много лет назад когда язык был молодой и развивался. именно поэтому многие из них не совсем соответствую нынешним требованием к коду на java. усугубляет ситуацию то что java была ориентирована на обратную совместимость (именно поэтому старые "костыли" никто не выпиливает, а лишь переписывают функционал выполняемый ими). учитывая все вышесказанное получается что вы используете не тот код для своих примеров.

Comment: 2 @Vlad: возможно когда речь идет о таких простых как пример выше код написаный в 1 строку выглядит эфектнее но это не означает что любой код который умещается в 1 строчку так же читабелен как многострочный. зачастую совсем наоборот, можете посмотреть примеры кода которые я приводил в ответах. 

если вы уповаете на то что строку кода написать легче чем написать 2-5 строк то вы недооцениваете скорость набора опытных программистов и возможности IDE.

p.s. если для вас принципиально показать красоту кода лучше предлагайте красивые ООП решения а не код писаный на другом языке для учебных примеров

Comment: @jmu: Я в курсе, и _именно по этому_ пропагандирую функциональный подход как более простой, чтобы новички привыкали думать не в терминах индексов и аллокаций, а в более высокоуровневых терминах преобразования множества значений.

---
То, что Java долгое время спала, есть с моей т. зр. огромный недостаток, который она, судя по планам на SE 8, скоро исправит. (С другой стороны, если вы покажете мне пример, в котором код на Java легче в понимании или компактнее, я буду вам благодарен.)

---
А как написать этот же код на "современной" Java? Мне и правда интересно.

Comment: @jmu: (1) Положа руку на сердце, вы и правда станете утверждать, что в данном случае однострочник не проще/красивее? У меня нету цикла и переменной-аккумулятора, которые релевантны не высокоуровневой задаче, а лишь самоочевидной реализации суммирования элементов списка.

(2) В ситуациях, где однострочник _менее_ понятен, я его и не привожу.

(3) Но всё же, как сделать наиболее красиво на Java, не ориентируясь на уровень умений новичка?

---
(Это ни в коем случае не критика данного ответа, ответ-то как раз ориентирован на новичка.)

Comment: я имею в виду что проблемы с написанием подобного кода возникают лишь у новичков. профессионалу плевать надо написать 2 строчки кода или 5, потому что закодить это самое простое, главное продумать структуру классов, взаимодействие итд итп. как результат: количество строчек кода не существенно.

в приведенном вами примере нарушаются принципы solid, что является плохим примером для java программиста (в то время как для C# это может быть приемлимо, тут уже вам виднее)

Comment: @jmu

      профессионалу плевать надо написать 2 строчки кода или 5, потому что закодить это самое простое, главное продумать структуру классов

Или послать структуру классов лесом, если инструмент позволяет.

      С утра съездил на мойку, в автосервис, заправился.. Если бы машины не было -- как бы всё это успел?

Comment: @jmu: для настолько тривиальной задачи не вижу смысла строить структуру классов. Кроме того, не вижу в своём коде нарушения SOLID по сравнению с циклами/счётчиком. LINQ-подход вроде бы лучше по пункту O (можно использовать произвольную свёртку списка) и D (не зависим от конкретики пробегания контейнера) из пяти.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "111py4@a4 5";
String[] numbers = str.split("");
int res = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length ; i++)
        {
            if (str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') {
                res += Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
            }
            else
            { System.out.print("");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sum(String str)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) sum+=Character.digit(str.charAt(i), 10);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Автор вопроса десять лет назад не определился, сумма чего ему нужна: _чисел_ (как в заголовке) или _цифр_ как в комментарии.